# How to mutate VueJS prop?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, vuejs2, vue-chartjs

Hi i'm having trouble understanding how to mutate a prop value in vue js. I'm using vue-chartjs to dynamically rerender a chart using chartjs. The behaviour works but I get a console message warning when I fire off the updateValues() function.

> Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be
>   overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a
>   data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being
>   mutated: "myData"

How do I properly mutate the prop?

```js
// Parent Component
<bar-graph :myData="dataCollection" :height="250"></bar-graph>

data () {
  return {
    dataCollection: {
      labels: [2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Sample Lables',
          backgroundColor: 'red',
          data: [5000, 5000, 5000, 5000, 5500, 5500, 10000, 5500, 5500]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
},
methods: {

  updateValues () {
    this.dataCollection = {
      labels: [5000, 5000, 5000, 5000, 5500, 5500, 10000, 5500, 5500],

      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Sample Lables',
          backgroundColor: 'red',
          data: [5000, 5000, 5000, 5000, 5500, 5500, 10000, 5500, 5500]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
      
      
//Child component bar graph

import { Bar } from 'vue-chartjs'

export default Bar.extend({

  props: ['myData'],

  mounted () {
    this.renderChart(this.myData, {responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false})
  },
  watch: {
    myData: function () {
      console.log('destroy')
      this._chart.destroy()
      this.renderChart(this.myData, {responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false})
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: The warning is correct. MyData is being received as a property from the parent component. You should update the bakes there and then the updated values will automatically be passed to your subcomponent and re-render.

Comment: update bakes? Can you explain further?

Comment: sorry autocorrect. I meant data.

Comment: So I need to update the data in the parent component? Is that not what i'm doing in updateValues()?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to "properly" mutate a prop, because it is a input to a component.

I recommend importing the data passed via the prop to the component's state and then using accordingly. By using this local copy, you avoid mutating the prop and getting that warning.

```js
export default Bar.extend({

  props: ['myData'],

  data() {
    return {
      passedData: null
    }
  }

  mounted() {
    // Import data from prop into component's state
    this.passedData == this.myData;
    // Use as desired
    this.renderChart(this.myData, {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false
    })
  },
  watch: {
    myData: function() {
      console.log('destroy')
      this._chart.destroy()
      this.renderChart(this.myData, {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

A comment / addition to @TheCascadian's answer: If `myData` is an `Object`, then `this.passedData` would be a reference to the same object, so you'll still get that warning. You might consider using `cloneDeep` from `lodash` to have a real inner copy of the property and use it internally accordingly.